# Using Unittest/PyTest/etc. to test a Python function that works with files

Tags: python, function, unit-testing

I have a function that takes in a path to an .mp3 or .m4a file and returns a string containing information extracted from the file using TinyTag (import statement removed for brevity):

```py
def create_search_term(path_to_song):
    tag = TinyTag.get(path_to_song)
    artist = tag.artist
    album = tag.album
    search_term = f"{album} {artist} Album Cover"
    return search_term
```

I've tested this manually, and it works with a real MP3 file path on my computer.  However, I'm trying to add unit tests to this project.  Is there a best practice to go writing a unit test for such a function?

A sample use case would be `"/path/to/bruce/springsteen/born_to_run.mp3"` taken as an input, and `"Born to Run Album Cover"` as a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch out `TinyTag` to produce a sample response, and then test the function result against that response:

```
from mock import patch

def test_create_search_term():
    with patch("__main__.TinyTag") as mock_tinytag:
        mock_tinytag.get.return_value.artist = "Bruce Springsteen"
        mock_tinytag.get.return_value.album = "Born to Run"
        assert create_search_term("foo") == "Born to Run Bruce Springsteen Album Cover"
```